# Android: Imageviews as method signatures?

Tags: java, android

In java, you can use method signatures as an efficient way to do things with common variables, like this

```
public class test{
    static int x=10;
    static int y=5;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(method(x));
        System.out.println(method(y));

    }
    public static int method(int insert){//Look at me im important
        return insert*5;
    }
}
```

So heres my question: In android(java), is it possible to do something similar  with imageviews? I think the following code will explain my question.

```
 private ImageView YOU, ENEMY;


 YOU = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.you);
 ENEMY = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.enemy);

...

//please ignore possible syntax errors from here on its just to demonstate the question

public void method(imageview character) {
    character.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dead);
}

...
method(YOU);
```

I would accept any closely related variation of this, thanks for reading

Comment: It should work. It is java.

Comment: Yes, that will work on Android.